# How do I do so that every time I select a checkbox the other is no longer selected? in Kotlin Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to know how I can obtain the value of the radiogroup that is to say which one I have selected, and save it in a variable in the kotlin activity I leave the xml file, and also the most important thing to do that every time one of the 2 RadioButtons is selected, the other is no longer selected, and so on.:

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group_min_max"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/max_selected"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Max"
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/min_selected"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
                android:padding="7dp"
                android:text="Min"
                />
        </RadioGroup>
```

and its kotlin activity file:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.CheckBox
import com.yr.iolite.R

class MinOrMax : AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_min_or_max)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read this? What are you stuck on? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton

Comment: I'm not sure about your question. You want to get which radio is selected and if user select any one of radios then  the user will not be able to check any radio further times. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you very much write it down as an answer, with this help I finished doing everything